# How to Parse KSOAP2 response in Android?

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I called a webservice using KSoap2 in Android, but the response I got is as follows. How to parse this ksoap response in Android?

> ResolveNamesResponse{ResponseMessages=anyType{ResolveNamesResponseMessage=anyType{MessageText=Multiple
>   results were found.; ResponseCode=ErrorNameResolutionMultipleResults;
>   DescriptiveLinkKey=0;
>   ResolutionSet=anyType{Resolution=anyType{Mailbox=anyType{Name=Amyj;
>   EmailAddress=Amyj@testsa.onmicrosoft.com; RoutingType=SMTP;
>   MailboxType=Mailbox; }; Contact=anyType{DisplayName=Amy John;
>   GivenName=Amy;
>   EmailAddresses=anyType{Entry=SIP:Amyj@test.onmicrosoft.com;
>   Entry=SMTP:Amyj@testsa.onmicrosoft.com; };
>   PhysicalAddresses=anyType{Entry=anyType{CountryOrRegion=China; }; };
>   ContactSource=ActiveDirectory; Surname=John; }; };
>   Resolution=anyType{Mailbox=anyType{Name=Amyraj;
>   EmailAddress=Amyraj@testsa.onmicrosoft.com; RoutingType=SMTP;
>   MailboxType=Mailbox; }; Contact=anyType{DisplayName=Amy Raj;
>   GivenName=Amy;
>   EmailAddresses=anyType{Entry=SIP:Amyraj@testsa.onmicrosoft.com;
>   Entry=SMTP:Amyraj@testsa.onmicrosoft.com; };
>   PhysicalAddresses=anyType{Entry=anyType{CountryOrRegion=India; }; };
>   ContactSource=ActiveDirectory; Surname=Raj; }; };
>   Resolution=anyType{Mailbox=anyType{Name=shine;
>   EmailAddress=shine@testsa.onmicrosoft.com; RoutingType=SMTP;
>   MailboxType=Mailbox; }; Contact=anyType{DisplayName=Shine Joseph;
>   GivenName=Shine;
>   EmailAddresses=anyType{Entry=SIP:shine@testsa.onmicrosoft.com;
>   Entry=SMTP:shine@testsa.onmicrosoft.com; };
>   PhysicalAddresses=anyType{Entry=anyType{CountryOrRegion=India; }; };
>   ContactSource=ActiveDirectory; Surname=Joseph; }; }; }; }; }; }

Answer (score 1):

Try This I think it will work

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

int cols = response.getPropertyCount();

for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {

    Object objectResponse = (Object) response.getProperty(i);
    SoapObject r =(SoapObject) objectResponse;

    String   key1=(String) r.getProperty("key1").toString();

    // Get the rest of your Properties by 
    // (String) r.getProperty("PropertyName").toString();            
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually this a known format if you know **`Java Script`**. These data in this format are infact **`JSON Object's and JSON Array's`**.So here is how you can parse this result.

eg:

```
private Bundle bundleResult=new Bundle();
private JSONObject JSONObj;
private JSONArray JSONArr;
Private SoapObject resultSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
/* gets our result in JSON String */
private String ResultObject = resultSOAP.getProperty(0).toString();

if (ResultObject.startsWith("{")) { // if JSON string is an object
    JSONObj = new JSONObject(ResultObject);
    Iterator<String> itr = JSONObj.keys();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        String Key = (String) itr.next();
        String Value = JSONObj.getString(Key);
        bundleResult.putString(Key, Value);
        // System.out.println(bundleResult.getString(Key));
    }
} else if (ResultObject.startsWith("[")) { // if JSON string is an array
    JSONArr = new JSONArray(ResultObject);
    System.out.println("length" + JSONArr.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < JSONArr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObj = (JSONObject) JSONArr.get(i);
        bundleResult.putString(String.valueOf(i), JSONObj.toString());
        // System.out.println(bundleResult.getString(i));
    } 
}
```

I hope this helps you solve your problem.